# PYSMI Library Mib Parser not giving "Description"

Tags: snmp, mib

I am using PYSMI Library to parse a MIB and it's giving me all the data I need except for description of each entry.

I am using their example code line for line on their website: http://snmplabs.com/pysmi/library-reference.html

I get everything from name, syntax, and so on except for description.

```
mibCompiler = MibCompiler(SmiStarParser(), JsonCodeGen(), 
CallbackWriter(self.json_create))
# search for source MIBs here
mibCompiler.addSources(*[FileReader(x) for x in src])
# search for source MIBs at Web sites
mibCompiler.addSources(*[HttpReader(*x) for x in self.http_src])
# never recompile MIBs with MACROs
mibCompiler.addSearchers(StubSearcher(*JsonCodeGen.baseMibs))
# run recursive MIB compilation
results = mibCompiler.compile(*self.input_mibs)
```

I expected to get a dictionary with everything, including entry descriptions but that is the only information I am not finding. Anyone know what I may be missing?

Comment: https://github.com/etingof/pysmi/issues

Answer (score 2):

PySMI documentation states:

> Most MIBs are very verbose. They contain many human-oriented descriptions and clarifications written in plain English. Those texts may be useful for MIB browser applications (to display those texts to human operator) but might not make any sense in other applications.
>
> To save space and CPU time, PySMI does not by default include those texts into transformed MIBs. However this can be reverted by adding –generate-mib-texts option.

I traced the code and figured out if you call the compiler like this: `mibCompiler.compile(*self.input_mibs, **dict(genTexts=True))`, it generates the descriptions.